# MySQL error 1215 cannot add foriegn key constraint

Tags: mysql

```
USE sales;
CREATE TABLE sales
(
   purchase_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
   date_of_purchase DATE,
   customer_id INT,
   idem_code VARCHAR(10)
);

CREATE TABLE customers
(
   customer_id INT,
   first_name VARCHAR(255),
   last_name VARCHAR(255),
   email_address VARCHAR(255),
   number_of_customer INT
);

ALTER TABLE sales
ADD FOREIGN KEY (customer_id) REFERENCES customers(customer_id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

I am a complete my SQL beginner. I came across 1215 my SQL error and have tried various ways to fix it but in vain. Please kindly help.

Thank you so much.

Comment: There is more to that error message. PLEASE always show us all the error message

Answer (score 1):

A Foreign key constraint must reference something `UNIQUE`.

In your customers table, the `customer_id` is a simple `INT`, there is nothing enforcing uniqueness.

I would strongly advise you to change the table customers definition to :

```
CREATE TABLE customers
(
   customer_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, -- <---- Check this line
   first_name VARCHAR(255),
   last_name VARCHAR(255),
   email_address VARCHAR(255),
   number_of_customer INT
);
```

`INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT` is a common way to write INT primary keys in MySQL, the same way you did in the table `sales`. You can use `BIGINT` instead of `INT`